# How to programmatically get the localized string as it displayed in iOS Settings App?

Tags: ios, swift, bundle, settings

I use Settings.bundle. There is an item about "Color". Here is a piece of file **Root.plist**:

```
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>Color</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Color </string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Titles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Green</string>
                <string>Red</string>
            </array>
            <key>Values</key>
            <array>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <integer>2</integer>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

And I localize it, for example, Spannish by file **es.lproj/Root.strings**:

```
"Blue" = "Azul";
"Green" = "Verde ";
"Red" = "Rojo";
```

They work fine on Settings App.

---

Now I need to programmatically get the localized color name as it displayed in iOS Settings App.

For example: I've got the value of 1 by

```
let r = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Color") as? Int
```

How can I get the String of "Verde" out of the value 1 or "Green"?

The key is: I don't want to duplicate the translations in **es.lproj/Localizable.strings** which is used by **func** NSLocalizedString().

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read It from Table like following:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Settings", ofType: "bundle") {
     let settingBundle = Bundle.init(path: path)
     print(settingBundle)
     let lString = NSLocalizedString("Color Name", tableName: "Root", bundle: settingBundle!, value: "Not found", comment: "")
     print(lString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
        if let serverStringsUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Root", withExtension: "strings", subdirectory: "Settings.bundle/en.lproj"),
        let serverStringsDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: serverStringsUrl) as? [String: String] {
            // Use your key to access your localized color value from serverStringsDict here. 
            print(serverStringsDict)
    }
```

When you load the file, you will need to specify the localized file. That is, the localized "Settings.bundle/xxx.lproj".